# Saved matplotlib animation file (mp4, gif) corrupted

Tags: python, animation, save

I have a python script that animates a curve and shades the area underneath the curve. The code is pretty much the same as for the example with the sine wave below, but the time evolution of the curve is read from a file. The animation that pops up when the program is done is fine, but the mp4 that is saved has issues with the shading beneath the curve: it accumulates. This is only the case for the curve that I read from the file and not for the simple sine wave. It also doesn't work if I save it as a gif with the writer set to imagemagick.
I wonder why my particular case fails and what I could try to fix it?

Here's the working example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
   line.set_data([], [])
   return line,

def animate(i):
   x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
   y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
   line.set_data(x, y)
   p = plt.fill_between(x, y, 0, facecolor="slateblue")
   return line, p,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
anim.save("testanimateion.mp4", writer='ffmpeg')
plt.show()
```

and a screenshot of the saved animation (it should be a wavy surface, the numerical solution of the linearized 1D shallow water equations):
[image: 1D shallow water model]

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: @fmw42 yes and I can make animations with it. They look fine as long as I don't use fill_between()